# Eligibility to work whilst waiting for decision

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

As discussed in a previous question:
 [When will my spouse be eligible for Indefinite Leave to Remain?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13700/when-will-my-spouse-be-eligible-for-indefinite-leave-to-remain)

We can make the application for indefinite leave to remain in December 2018. My wife's current visa expires in February 2019, and currently the Home Office is stating that processing time for indefinite leave to remain can be up to 6 months.

What happens if the expiry date of her current work permit passes and we have not yet been informed of a decision by the home office? Is she allowed to keep working under the terms of her current visa whilst a decision is pending?